# Rank Over by Length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This one is tough.

- I have a table that has duplicates
- The table has no unique ID or Date
- The only thing different is the length of the description
- The table only has 2 columns: RestuarantID and Description
- I need to delete the duplicate with the shortest description

RestuarantID        |    Description

1849 |  Restaurant\1849 (1849)

1849 |  Restaurant\Francis(1849)

I can do a rank over, but there is no guarantee the description will be in order

```
SELECT  RestuarantID , 
            [Description] , 
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY RestuarantID ORDER BY [Description]) AS MyRank
            FROM FinalOutPut
```

What I need to do, is rank over by Description Length.

**The one with the shortest length needs to be deleted.**

Comment: then do just that: `OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEN(Description))`

Comment: It works, add it and I will give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

#### EDIT: working example

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT, description VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'123'),(1,'1234'),(1,'12'),(2,'abc'),(2,'ab');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

WITH MyCTE AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEN(Description) DESC) AS Nr
         ,ID
         ,Description 
   FROM @tbl
)
DELETE FROM MyCTE WHERE Nr>1; --will keep just the longest

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: `The one with the shortest length needs to be deleted`, that would mean to order by `LEN() ASC` and delete where rn = 1

Comment: @Lamak My assumption was, that the longest should stay. If there are only two of them it does not matter, if there are more, I think it is correct to delete all except the longest, but this is OP's decision. Anyway, thx for the hint!